# Persist object in PostPersist, PostUpdate events

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a logger which use Doctrine to writes in DB.  And I need log some events in Doctrine `PostPersist`, `PostUpdate` and `PreRemove` handlers of an [Entity Listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners).
But a `flush` operation is officialy unsupported (and sometimes cause fatal errors if neglect it) in these handlers.
I have encountered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374155/doctrine-inserting-in-postpersist-event), but the solution is to defer a flush to the end of a currently performing flush, which is not suit me, cause I need to insert entry right in the handlers, e.g. in order not to lose object id during remove operation.
I have a `LogManager` and want that this `add-log-entry` operation be the same - no matter whether you invoke it from some handler or from some another place in code.
I wonder is there a way to persist objects in the handlers? (May be by using another EntityManager ...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [onFlush](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) event that I think suites well to your needs. Instead of using flush method you have to recompute/compute changes manually. See the link.

From Doctrine2 documentation:

- If you create and persist a new entity in onFlush, then calling EntityManager#persist() is not enough. You have to execute an additional call to `$unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity)`.
- Changing primitive fields or associations requires you to explicitly trigger a re-computation of the changeset of the affected entity. This can be done by calling `$unitOfWork->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity)`.

Comment: Yes, but it's not so fit me now, cause I have a log manager service which can be used throughout all the application, not just in these handlers. And I have almost the same situation (except that I use postFlush)  that you have suggested, and it had worked well till I added this very logging in preRemove handler which brought me to the situation that I have no id of removing object in *pre*Flush operation. So I looking for some more independent way of  safe logging ( when I would can use this logger in any place of the application ).

Comment: Is it the one possible variant of doing this? What do you think about one more em?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well. In **onFlush** (not postFlush neither preFlush) you can get all entities that are going to be inserted, deleted or updated. You have also id of entity that will be removed.