# need explanation on postPersist and data flushed

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i had trouble with an entity who was not flushed correctly.

In a service, i setted somme values. before flushing them in the service, i call another service and i saw there was a listener linked.
In this listener, there was a postPersist method in witch was called "$entityManager->flush();"

It was the source of my problem.

I found this post : [Doctrine inserting in postPersist event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374155/doctrine-inserting-in-postpersist-event)

So, i deleted the flush who was done in the postPersist.

But i don't understand the need of the method postFlush.

In my case, data is flushed even if i don't have this method. how is it possible that the properties setted in the listener are flushed correctly without this event ?

If i look other entry points, i see that i need to declare the postFlush event and i see the need of this method.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to flush in a postPersist event, because it will be done soon, just after Persist. You don't need to use all the functions of the list, neither declaring them.

ps.: Only if you need to get/set data before persist/flush. You would need to compute changes then get them in the action 'couple' (e.g prePersist and postPersist, preUpdate and postUpdate). 
docs says:

> Changes to fields of the passed entities are not recognized by the
>   flush operation anymore, use the computed change-set passed to the
>   event to modify primitive field values.

and

> getEntityChangeSet() to get a copy of the changeset array. Changes to
>   this returned array do not affect updating.

PostFlush

The postFlush is made at the end of a flush operation. According to the docs this event is not a lifecycle callback.  You can use it to set something after registering, or even send notifications, clearly with postFlush you won't need to worry about lifeCycle events.

> postFlush - The postFlush event occurs at the end of a flush
>   operation. This event is not a lifecycle callback.

For postPersist in the docs

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

Here you can have ids if you need before flush.

You can check the docs about LifeCycleEvents here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events